# Power of a test in the case of Bernoulli sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

I'm solving the following exercise:

---

We consider a sample $X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n}$ of size $n$ of the Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\theta,$ where $0<\theta<1$

1. Prove that this family of distribution possesses the MLR property (monotone likelihood ratio).
2. What is the test statistic and the critical region of the UMP (uniformly most powerful) tests for testing $H_{0}: \theta \leq 0.2$ against $H_{1}: \theta>0.2$?
3. For $n=4,$ compute the threshold $s$ of the test with critical region $C_{s}=$ $\{\bar{X} \geq s\}$ so that the level is equal to $0.05$?
4. For $n=4,$ write the R code for evaluating the **power of the test** of question 3 when the alternative is $\theta=0.6$?

---

From [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Power_(statistics)), the power of a **binary** hypothesis test is the probability that the test rejects the null hypothesis ($H_0$) when a **specific** alternative hypothesis ($H_1$) is true.

**My questions:**

1. What do **binary** and **specific** mean in the context of above sentence?
2. My attempt at question 3 is as follows. We have $$\alpha = \mathbb P [C_s | \theta = 0.2] = \mathbb P [\bar X \ge s | \theta = 0.2] = \mathbb P [\operatorname{Bin}(4,0.2) \ge 4s]$$

   - If $4s=0$ then $\alpha = 1$
   - If $4s=1$ then $\alpha = 0.594$
   - If $4s=2$ then $\alpha = 0.1808$
   - If $4s=3$ then $\alpha = 0.272$
   - If $4s=4$ then $\alpha = 0.0016$

Because the binomial distribution is discrete, I don't know which $s$ is an appropriate answer. Please elaborate on this issue!

3. My attempt at question 4 is as follows: the power of the test is $\mathbb P[ C_s | \theta = 0.6] = \mathbb P [\operatorname{Bin}(4, 0.6) \ge 4s]$ with $s$ given by question 3. Is this solution correct?

Comment: Your key question is #2, so let's focus on that.  Its answer depends: does your concept of a test include randomized test procedures or not?

Comment: @whuber my lecture does not mention anything about randomized test procedures. Actually, my main concern is question 3, i.e. the definition of power of a test. In case $H_1$ is composite, how can we compute the power of a test?

Comment: The power is a function defined on $H_1.$

Comment: @whuber do you mean the following? Assume that $H_0: \theta \in \Theta_0$ and $H_1: \theta \in \Theta_1$. Then the significance level $\alpha = \sup_{\theta' \in \Theta_0} \mathbb P[C| \theta = \theta']$, whereas the power of a test is the function $\Theta_1 \to [0,1], \quad \theta' \mapsto \mathbb P[C| \theta = \theta']$. Here $C$ is the rejection region and $\theta$ the true parameter.

Comment: That notation is superfluous: $H_0$ and $H_1$ are, by definition, sets of distributions.  The power is a function defined on $H_1.$ For $\theta\in H_1,$ the value of the power function at $\theta$ is the chance of rejecting the null when sampling from $\theta.$

Comment: @whuber in your notations, the significance level $\alpha = \sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} \mathbb P_{\theta}[C]$, whereas the power of a test is the function $\Theta_1 \to [0,1], \quad \theta \mapsto \mathbb P_{\theta}[C]$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, understanding $\Theta_1=H_1$ and $\Theta_0=H_0.$

Comment: Thank you so much @whuber! Your explanation really gets things clearer to me.